# nested store function is not a function at runtime (zustand store, immer, persist, typescript)

Tags: reactjs, runtime-error, store, immer.js, zustand

I've got a problem in a next.js typescript project where i'm using zustand store with persist and immer: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand

If the toggle_slide_over function is outside of the session_setup object, it works.

If it is inside, it throws runtime error 'not a function'.

Why & how do i fix this?

Interface:

```
export interface MyAppState {
  session_setup: {
    slide_over_open: boolean,
    toggle_slide_over: (new_toggle_state: boolean) => void,
    ...
  },
  session_setup_toggle_slide_over: (new_toggle_state: boolean) => void,
  ...
}
```

Function declarations inside doPersist():

```
const doPersist: () any => { return persist((set) => ({
   session_setup: {
      ...
      toggle_slide_over: (new_toggle_state) => set(
           produce(state => { state.session_setup.slide_over_open = new_toggle_state })
      ),
   },
   session_setup_toggle_slide_over: (new_toggle_state) => set(
        produce(state => { state.session_setup.slide_over_open = new_toggle_state })
   ),
...
```

How they are retrieved in React:

```
// When nested:
const toggle_slide_over = useMyAppStore(state => state.session_setup.toggle_slide_over)

// When not nested:
const toggle_slide_over = useMyAppStore(state => state.session_setup_toggle_slide_over)
```

How they are used:

```
onClick={() => toggle_slide_over(new_state)}
```

Store:

```
const initializeStoreByEnv = (): any => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') return devtools(doPersist())
    else return doPersist()
}

export const useMyAppStore = create<MyAppState>()(
    initializeStoreByEnv()
)
```

I've searched for related zustand/immer/redux/functions nested in objects/function not a function at runtime errors but haven't found anything useful, yet...

I'm working around this by just prefixing out-of-object functions with 'session_setup_', which is ok atm, but will get xxxl names with another level of nesting objects.

Answer (score -1):

I completely ran into the same issue. I had **nested slices, containing data and functions**, which i wanted to persist using `zustand/persist`. I ended up going with this following approach:

src/zustand/store/index.ts

```js
export const useMyAppStore = create<MyAppState>()(
  persist(
    (...args) => ({
      foo: createFooSlice(...args)
    }),
    {
      name: "app-store",
      merge: (persistedState, defaultState) => {
        if (!persistedState || typeof persistedState !== "object") {
          return defaultState;
        }

        let resultState: MyAppState = { ...defaultState };
        const keys = Object.keys(defaultState) as (keyof MyAppState)[]

        keys.forEach((key) => {
          if (key in persistedState) {
            //@ts-ignore // TypeScript currently don't recognize that key exists in localState
            const state = persistedState[key]
            if (!!state) {
              resultState = { ...resultState, [key]: { ...defaultState[key], ...state }}
            }
          }
        })

        return resultState;
      }
    }
  )
```